# Checking session, keeping PHP connection alive

Tags: php, connection

We have a streaming site which has a loggin system based on PHP sessions. After the user starts the stream, if another person is connecting with the same account, I need to terminate the first session and kill the page. The only way I can think of is using Ajax, but I'm not sure how secure is that. Is there any way to output the page in php and after the page is served to the user and after that the script to keep checking if another user has logged in with the same account and kill the page? Tried using output buffering and sleep, no luck so far.

Comment: I don't think ajax helps you. If I understand you correct you want to stop the streaming? This has to be done through the streaming-server, proxy, or whatever. Ajax is not reliable. As for the session datasage is right. If you save the session_id into the database with the user_id, and check it on every request, the user is logged out, when he authenticates with a new session-id. The case, that the user uses the same session id on different devices you should ignore at the beginning if you ask me.

Comment: Yes, the main reason for this is to stop the streaming, because after the users starts the video, he probably won't trigger any requests in order to be logged out. I will look more into the streaming-server and proxy for it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to keep track of sessions in a database or other storage system. This data should have a reference to the user. And get cleaned up on a regular basis.

If you kill an existing session, the user in that session wont be pushed out until the next server request. So in the background, you want to 'ping' the server, just make an ajax request, until it fails. On failure, redirect the user back to a login page.

Now this is not foolproof. A client could interfere with, block or redirect the ping requests. But if they were to access another page in your system, they would be forced to login again.

Comment: I am storing the sessions in a database, as for ajax, we really need to make sure the client can't modify it so easily. I was wondering if there is any workaround ajax, like using sleep in php while keeping the connection alive and checking database that way .Since the user is watching a movie or w/e he won't be surfing the site so he won't make any server request.I'm newbie in web development, maybe the question is a bit dumb :)

Comment: Http is stateless protocol. It doesn't really know or care that you have a session. Sessions are simulated by passing a cookie (or auth headers in some cases). You could explore WebSocket, but its browser support is still somewhat limited. Otherwise you may want to look at maintaining a session in your streaming server if you are using one.